# Get substrings from excel cell

Tags: excel

I have a column A in a spreadsheet.

```
_Default = "20";
AdminBlock = "00";
CallRefused = "01";
LearnedBlock = "02";
```

What I want is to split it into two columns such as

```
_Default      20
AdminBlock    00 
CallRefused   01 
LearnedBlock  02
```

My tried formula is:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("=",A1,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a one-off issue, just use the 'text to columns' on the data menu, specifying = as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Column B's formula:

```
=TRIM(MID(TRIM(A1),1,FIND("=",TRIM(A1))-1))
```

Column C's formula:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(TRIM(A1),FIND("=",TRIM(A1))+1,LEN(TRIM(A1))),"""",""),";",""))
```